# nginx group http auth

Tags: authentication, nginx

coming from apache2 the only feature i cannot archive: have users in a password-database (`htpasswd`) and allow the access to different files/folders/virtual servers.

Basic http auth I enabled works:

```
location ~ ^/a/ {
    # should allow access for user1, user2
    auth_basic            "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/auth/file_a;
}
location ~ ^/b/ {
    # should allow access for user2, user3
    auth_basic            "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/auth/file_b;
}
```

If I have *user1*, *user2* in `file_a` and *user2*, *user3* in `file_b`, this works but I have to update both files when I change the password for *user2* (password should be the same for all locations). Since I will have >15 different locations with different access rights and >10 users, this is not really easy to handle. (I love fine grained access rights!)

With Apache I defined different groups for each location and required the right group. Changing access was as easy as adding/removing users to groups.

Is there something like that or how can this scenario be handled easily with nginx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally manage it like this with basic http auth:

- For each group I have a seperate password file, eg `group_a.auth`, `group_b.auth`, ...
- In addition, I have a file where each user and password is written, eg `passwords.txt`
- `passwords.txt` has the same format like auth files, so something like `user1:password_hash`
- I have a ruby script `update.rb` to sync user's passwords from `password.txt` to all `.auth` files (well more a wrapper to `sed`):

Ruby script `update.rb`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

passwords = File.new("./passwords.txt","r")

while pwline = passwords.gets
    pwline.strip!
    next if pwline.empty?

    user, _ = pwline.split(':')
    %x(sed -i 's/#{user}:.*/#{pwline.gsub('/','\/')}/g' *.auth)
end
```

- To update a user's password: update password in `passwords.txt` and execute `update.rb`
- To add a user to a group (eg `new_user` to `group_a`): open `group_a.auth` and add the line `new_user:`. Then add `new_user:password_hash` to `passwords.txt` if the user is not already present and finally run `update.rb`

Answer (score 16):

You can get this working using `AuthDigest` module and realms as groups - you'll have multiple entries for one user, but you can have them line after line in a single file. Not perfect, but better than the nightmare you have now.

Small change in configuration (see auth_digest and user_file for 2nd location):

```
location ~ ^/a/ {
    # should allow access for user1, user2
    auth_digest            "Restricted";
    auth_digest_user_file  /etc/nginx/auth/file_a;
}
location ~ ^/b/ {
    # should allow access for user2, user3
    auth_digest            "Restricted2";
    auth_digest_user_file  /etc/nginx/auth/file_a;
}
```

and file_a:

```
user1:Restricted1:password_hash
user2:Restricted1:password_hash
user2:Restricted2:password_hash
user3:Restricted2:password_hash
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using a script nginx-groups.pl that parses apache style password and groups files and generates individual password files for each group.  So it essentially does the same thing as the Ruby script in Markus' answer but it uses only one single file for all groups and the group file is in the same format as for apache.

The current version of the script is:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;

die "Usage: $0 USERSFILE GROUPSFILE\n" unless @ARGV == 2;
my ($users_file, $groups_file) = @ARGV;

my %users;
open my $fh, "<$users_file" or die "cannot open '$users_file': $!\n";
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($name, $password) = split /:/, $line, 2;
    next if !defined $password;
    $users{$name} = $line;
}

open my $fh, "<$groups_file" or die "cannot open '$groups_file': $!\n";
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    my ($name, $members) = split /:/, $line, 2 or next;
    next if !defined $members;
    $name =~ s/[ \t]//g;
    next if $name eq '';
    my @members = grep { length $_ && exists $users{$_} } 
                  split /[ \t\r\n]+/, $members;

    my $groups_users_file = $name . '.users';

    print "Writing users file '$groups_users_file'.\n";

    open my $wh, ">$groups_users_file" 
        or die "Cannot open '$groups_users_file' for writing: $!\n";

    foreach my $user (@members) {
        print $wh "$users{$user}\n"
            or die "Cannot write to '$groups_users_file': $!\n";
    }

    close $wh or die "Cannot close '$groups_users_file': $!\n";
}
```

Save it under whatever name you like and make it executable.  Invoking it without arguments will print a short usage info.

See http://www.guido-flohr.net/group-authentication-for-nginx/ for details!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13697810)

Comment: Okay, @unamata-sanatarai, I have added the source code of the script.